# How to make the group header different than the table entries in NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

Is there any way to use a different column for the first column *in* the group? By default it uses the same as the "Group Title" (the one with the "expand" triangle).
E.g. I want to bind the "Group" row  to departmentTitle and the first column of the items in the group should have employeeTitle.

Like this:

```
-> departmentTitle
-->employeeTitle
-->employeeTitle
-->employeeTitle
-->employeeTitle
```

By default they use the same column like this:

```
-> departmentTitle
-->departmentTitle
-->departmentTitle
-->departmentTitle
-->departmentTitle
```

How can I change them from using the same column? I can just set it to "title" and make a `return self.employeeTitle` method but then I have to make that KVO compliant and mess up my model with workaround stuff. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i might be late to answer this question, but here's what i did (it's not the most ellegant way of doing it, i'm certain)

you could have a property called "title" and bind the column to it.
also, define a property "departmentTitle" and "employeeTitle" which you'd initialize depending on whether an object is group or child object.
then define the "title" property's getter to return either "departmentTitle" or "employeeTitle" depending on your needs. it would look something like this:

```
- (NSString) title {
if (isLeaf) {
return self.employeeTitle;
}
else {
return self.departmentTitle;
}
}
```

as i said, it's not an ellegant solution but it worked like a charm for me.